# Can i use DeepSecurity API (with java sdk) to check virus list scaned and detected?

Tags: deepsecurity

Can i use **deep security API** (with *java* *sdk* ) to check virus detected and scaned in deep security ?

I'm using Eclipse in my environment.

Thank's for help in advance!

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you're trying to do? If you can find the task/action in the Help Center (https://help.deepsecurity.trendmicro.com/), then it's easier to relate that to a particular api (https://automation.deepsecurity.trendmicro.com/article/fr/api-reference?platform=on-premise)

Comment: Thank you Morgan,
I looked at the official documentation (which you sent me) but I did not find how I can display the reports on the state of agents such as: the total number of viruses scanned and blocked, or top 10 viruses detected ....

I used Java SDK in my eclipse, when I build (as java application) the result is displayed but it's not what I want and what I told you above

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the extra detail, that you're trying to use the API to get, ie. "the total number of viruses scanned and blocked, or top 10 viruses detected."

I can tell you that the new rest API whose Java SDK I understand you are using does not support that functionality directly. If there's a report in DSM that would contain the info you're looking for, you could use the ScheduledTask API to generate that report: https://automation.deepsecurity.trendmicro.com/article/fr/maintain-protection-using-scheduled-tasks?platform=on-premise

Comment: Thank's @Morgan for your answer, 
I just saw the links that you sent me there is ScheduledTasksApi but unfortunately I think that method also does not allow to have the report as I told you in the form of a csv our json file  (via the API in eclipse of course)

for ScheduledTasksApi: it just allows to manage ScheduledTasks in DSM!

Comment: You can trigger a scheduled task to run by setting "runnow" to "true". But if the report does not exist in the DSM, then that obviously doesn't solve the problem.